# asp.net mvc 3 iis 7.5 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

**EDIT**

Well works fine on my dev machine if I'm using Visual Development Server.
However, if I set to Use Local IIS WebServer (project url set at `http://localhost/myapp`) it DOESN'T work I get a 401 error.

Deploys fine from visual studio 2010 using msdeploy to IIS 7.5 with a site named apps.mydomain.com/myapp.  So essentially I want to browse to http://apps.mydomain.com/myapp but when I do I get 404 error.

- I have Windows authentication enabled only on the site everything else is disabled.
- I have installed hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368.
- App pool .NET 4 integrated pipeline.  I have tried classic pipeline also but doesn't work.
- executed %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir  still doesn't work

What am I doing wrong or do I need to do anything else?

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });      

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()        
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }     
}
```

Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/notfound"></error>
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="~/error/notfound" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="~/error" />
    </httpErrors>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If possible, you should remote into the server in question and request the page locally.  If nothing else, you should get a more helpful error than just 404.

Comment: You can also check if the Application pool is running Classic or Integrated (needs to be integrated)

Comment: Drop an HTML file in the root of the site - can you see that in the browser? If not, it could be a DNS resolution issue. Does the domain definitely resolve to the IP address of the server?

Comment: I dropped a HTML file in the root of the site and this works.  I should add there are other asp.net web forms apps in root website that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an issue with the bindings.

Also you can check apps.mydomain.com in the DNS.

P.S. If you're not sure with your routes, you can use this cool small library: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: "@nZeus" I think you're right about the issue with the bindings.   Created a new dns entry myapp.mydomain.com (original location was apps.mydomain.com/myapp which didn't work) and my mvc app comes up at this url. Any reason why this is?

Comment: What happens when you enter http://apps.mydomain.com ? You should either see "IIS Welcome" page or website content. If you see 404 than run "ping apps.mydomain.com" and "tracert apps.mydomain.com" in the commend line.